# converting UTC to local time automatically using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Im using MySQL with PHP, and the project is a kind of notification manager

if some one does some thing, a new notification need to be posted in the common post-ground

the issue is - we have users from multiple timezones, currently Im using "datetime" as the field type, so what ever I enter converts into UTC

for example: Im from India(+5:30) and if I create a notification at  21/3/2015 22:50:00, it is saving in DB as 21/3/2015 17:20:00

storing works perfectly well from all zones, but while retrieving it shows for me as 21/3/2015 17:20:00(UTC) but Im expecting in my timezone(IST +5:30) so what Im expecting is 21/3/2015 22:50:00.

is there a way to mention in the query itself to get the time converted in the fetching itself?

or any other way to convert and process further?

any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: The easiest alternative to doing it in the query is to use PHP's DateTime objects

Comment: `timestamp` fields do UTC conversion, not `datetime` fields.  At least [according to the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html).  Perhaps it's happening on the PHP side of things?  Please show some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `convert_tz` so while selecting you can use the following

```
mysql> select convert_tz('2015-03-21 17:20:00','+00:00','+05:30') as ist_time;
+---------------------+
| ist_time            |
+---------------------+
| 2015-03-21 22:50:00 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

All you need to do is to change the hard coded date `'2015-03-21 17:20:00'` to your column name in the selection.

Comment: cool @Abhik, my question is how do I set the +5:30? I know that mine is IST so I set +5:30, how to make it dynamic, so it finds the clients timezone and operates accordingly?

Comment: Well thats a big topic, if you store users timezone in db then for each user while they are viewing the data you need to convert the utc to timezone of the user. You can check out php `DateTime` object which has some cool functions for timezone conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your client TimeZone through [JSTZ](http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/)

In your php file, you can simply convert the date after you received the from mysql:

```
 $date = new DateTime($date . " " . "UTC");
 $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timeZoneTo));//$timeZoneTo you get it from JSTZ
```

Comment: This is reasonably, but do understand that JSTZ will take an *educated guess* at the time zone.  It's very often correct, but sometimes it's not.